# Finding some homogeneous generators of an ideal.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, extension-field

Suppose that $\mathfrak a$ is an homogeneous ideal of $K[T_1,\ldots, T_n]$ where $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ and $T_1,\ldots,T_n$ are indeterminates. Moreover suppose that $\mathfrak a$ has a system of generators in $L[T_1,\ldots, T_n]$ where $L\subseteq K$.

Can I find a system of **homogeneous** generators in $L[T_1,\ldots, T_n]$?

thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't the definition of "homogeneous ideal" directly allow you to split the generators into homogeneous pieces in the ideal?

Comment: @rschwieb Not if your definition is "has a homogeneous generating set". The two are equivalent by if the latter then a little work is required.

Comment: @TomOldfield I guess that makes sense... I had only ever used the "homogeneous parts of elements are in the ideal" definition.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah, it's swings and roundabouts really, I just thought I'd mention it so people know the question has more merit than just "by definition", which is otherwise a fair assumption to make!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an ideal $I$ in a polynomial ring is homogeneous iff for every element $f$ in the ideal, each of the homogeneous parts of $f$ also lie in $I$. The homogeneous parts of the given generators then perform as required.